# Positioning a div (present at the bottom of jsp file) to be displayed on top of all other divs

Tags: css

I have a page something like this

```
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="bottom">
</div>
```

I want an output which displays bottom first then top..
How can i achieve this using CSS ??

Comment: Can you give any more context? Like why you can't just put id=bottom above id=top in the HTML?

Comment: Actually #bottom is a included page which has content in #top...
So i want the execution to be #top #bottom order...but when it comes to display, i want #bottom to be displayed on page top ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question means, the following.. "You would want to place div#bottom on top of the other drawn DOM elements below". DOM ordering.

#### If you want #top and #bottom to be independent DOM elements.

```
div#top {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

div#bottom {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  top:10%;
  left:4%;
}
```

- The top and left values are values of your choice, the above example places the bottom inside the top.
- positioning - Can be used to manipulate the same. You could use fixed element inside a huge encompassing div. But use fixed only if you are sure that the DOM contents is to be shown even on a overflow. 'relative' positioning might as well work when you are working reference is the body or the Root Node class or element.

#### If you want to control how DOM displays these elements. Then you might have to use javascript with CSS to achieve this. Like say

```
document.getElementById('bottom').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('top').style.display = 'none';
```

After a timeout 
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('top').style.display = 'block';
   }, 200);

#### Since independent div's are not the best way to do this, would rather suggest you to try Something like this

```
<div id="top_div">
   <div id="bottom_div">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with the help of "positions" u can achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page is rendered from Top to Bottom. Reverse your div tags as in :

```
<div id="bottom">
</div>
<div id="top">
</div>
```

unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

Comment: I have a jsp included in #bottom which loads updated content only when included at the bottom of the page...but i need to displat #bottom at the top of page

Answer (score 0):

Using Position in css it should work o.w try below

```
<div id="bottom">
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div id="top">
</div>
```